# How do I get the context of an item from a class (css & Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

```
I have a few images with css -> $(".toolTip").

<img  width="150" height="200" src="<?php echo $avatarPath; ?> " class="toolTip" alt="<?php echo $control_panel_id ?>"/>
```

In my code, I want to refer to the image as a tag, and not to the class. I want to apply jquery methods, to the specific image that I hover over (taking into account that all those images have the same class name..)

Is there a way to do this ... $(".toolTip").  and then getSelector() method, so that I will get the specific element the mouse hovered over?!?

UPDATE:
but when I try to put mouseover, it doesnt work..it positions the div near the first picture...

```
 $('body').append('<div style="position:absolute; z-index:9999; background-color:#FF0000; width:150px; height:400px;" id="tooltip_outer"><div style="position:absolute; z-index:9999;" id="tooltip_inner"></div></div>');
 var $toolTip_inner=$("#tooltip_inner"); 
 var $toolTip_outer=$("#tooltip_outer");
// var $toolTip;



 if(!$(".toolTip"))
 {

     return;
 }


 $(".toolTip").hover(function(){

      $toolTip=$(this);
     if( $(this).attr("alt") )
     {  

        $tooltipText=$(this).attr("alt"); 

        $(this).attr("alt",'');

     }
     else
     {

       $bug[0]="There is no title a$toolTip_outerribute<br/>";
     }

      var t_width=$(this).outerWidth();
     var t_height=$(this).outerHeight();

    //Move css
     $toolTip_outer.css({
     'top':t_height-60,
     'left':t_width-140

    });

        $toolTip_inner.html("<p>The control panel id is: "+$tooltipText+" </p>");        
        $toolTip_outer.show();

    },  
  function(){
      //hide tooltip
    $toolTip_outer.hide();  
    //fix text
    $toolTip_inner.html(''); 

     if($toolTip_inner)
     {   // restore title text
        $(this).attr('alt',$tooltipText); 
     }

  })
```

The location takes into account the first image only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".toolTip").hover(function(){
    // On mouseover
    // Here 'this' refers to the DOM Element that is hovered over
    // $(this) is a jQuery object containing it
}, function(){
    // Here 'this' refers to the DOM Element that was hovered over
    // $(this) is a jQuery object containing it
});
```

If you use `$(this)` more than once in a function either use [chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/), or store `$(this)` in a variable like `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this` to speed up your script.

**Update**

First of all although this doesn't solve your problem, but you should know that `!$(".toolTip")` is always false: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm7Kn/ You probably want `!$(".toolTip").length` which will only be false if there were no matches to the selector `.toolTip`.

Your problem probably occurs around here:

```
$toolTip_outer.css({
    'top':t_height-60,
    'left':t_width-140
});
```

Where you position the toolTip outer relative to it's offset parent rather than relative to the tooltip you're currently hovering over. You may have meant to use $ev_x to position close to the mouse cursor, or you may have wanted to use jQuery's [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) function like `$toolTip.position().top` and `$toolTip.position().left` to get the position of the image that is being hovered over and put the tooltip near those co-ordinates. I'm not sure of your exact intentions though.

Comment: Thats incorrect, because it refers to .toolTip,,,which means the first image is only effected by the hover..I have 6 images with that class...I need it to refer to the specific image , not to the class..

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd It does, try it out. I'll make an example for you in jQuery

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Here is an example for you adding a border using jQuery's `hover()` and `css()` functions: http://jsfiddle.net/urUBU/

Comment: I want this t_height=$toolTip.outerHeight();
to be the height of the current image..It seems that $toolTip stores $this of the first element that has teh .toolTip class

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd `$(this).outerHeight();` will be the height of the hovered image as you want, but you probably want to take into account the position of that image as well, not just it's height. I wrote an update for you. Also with a note about `$('.toolTip')` always being truthy so your sanity check to make sure there is an element with the toolTip class doesn't work, but there is an easy fix.

Comment: I have an 6 images aligned vertically.. I want the div to be placed beside the one image that I hover over

Comment: The width is 150 and height is 200 ,,no matter which image I hover over